# How do I log an object property that is nested in an array inside an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

Basically, I want to print an object lying here:

```
let array = [
[{property: 'text',
property2: 'text'}],
{ property3: 'text',
property4: 'text'}];
```

Thank you.

Comment: In what sense? Are you asking about `console.log`, the function that prints in the dev console, or how to grab elements in an array?

Comment: `array[0][0].property`?

Comment: console.log() //

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

```
console.log(array[position].property)
```